# flexbox ,чтобы было в центре и 3 блок

Tags: html, css

Как сделать на `flexbox` ,чтобы было в центре и 3й блок был большой?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
       <div class="content">
        <div class="section_item">
          <img src="img/s2item1.png" alt="">
          <p>Занятия в уютной атмосфере  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="section_item">
          <img src="img/s2item2.png" alt="">
          <p>У наших преподавателей есть
              минимум три года практики за рубежом  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="section_2-item">
          <img src="img/s2item3.png" alt="">
            <p>Бесплатная заморозка на один месяц,
                если вы решили уехать в отпуск 
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="section_2-item">
           <img src="img/s2item4.png" alt="">
            <p> </p>
          </div>
          <div class="section_2-item">
            <img src="img/s2item5.png" alt="">
             <p>Удобное время занятий совместимое с вашим графиком </p> 
          </div>
```

Comment: Автор вопроса, если вам помог ответ, то не забудьте отметить его решением. Также не забывайте отмечать другие ответы в других ваших вопросах

Answer (score 1):

С помощью  `flex-grow`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-item {
  margin: 0.2rem;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 39vh;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.grow {
  background-color: forestgreen;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item grow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```